# How does onclick of Android work???( 'Two taps' problem crashes me!)

Tags: android

Fist of all, I am the Android beginner.
I do know that Button's `onClick()` in `onCreate()` does not exist. However I do not know why actually.
My problem is as follows.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.change_text);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (UPDATE_TEXT == 2) {
                    UPDATE_TEXT = 1;
                } else {
                    UPDATE_TEXT = 2;
                }
                .....................
}
```

I found that as long as I add a judgment statement, the button will must have to click twice to achieve the function I need. So why judgment statement does not work in `onlick()`?

Comment: Perhaps English is not your first language, but you need to clarify your question. For example, what is a "judgement statement"?

Comment: Sry, I mean the "judgment sentence"

Comment: Sry, I mean that just like "judgment grammar" (```if (){} else {}```). My code is mainly to achieve such a function that main activity will change content in the ```textView``` as long as I click the button. And I use thread to realize the function of judging click. I  found that as long as I add judgment syntax, I must have to click twice to achieve my goal (change content). I want to solve it and know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute a statement with two clicks then just put the counter there and increment the counter by +1 and check every time that the counter modulo 2.

Like this inside your click method...

```
if(counter % 2 == 0){
....execute yout statement
}
```

> But the real catch is what happens if the user clicks the button only
> one time? and after some time user decided to click on it again? So in
> that case this system fails because the counter still at its previous
> odd number state so the user needs to click one time this time.

> So to avoid this problem you need to check the timing difference
> between two clicks and if the time is favorable then execute the
> function else reset the counter back to zero.

Comment: I want to execute by one tap (just click one time). But it does not work because judgment grammar exists. There is ```new Thread(new Runnable(){ }``` after.

Comment: I think two taps will launch multiple threads and it is creating some errors or mismatch in your logic.

Comment: @Mr8god Great to know!

Answer (score 0):

In general, in the click handler it is worth adding the number of clicks, and if it was not called, then a thread is called that sleeps for a second. Ask the thread determines which message to send to the handler, based on how many clicks occurred during this time. Handler, based on the message, executes the necessary code

Comment: How can i add the number of clicks? And it must be important ? I don't know it before.